# Unable to create documentation with Sphinx and Google docstrings

Tags: python, python-sphinx, setuptools, docstring, sphinx-napoleon

I am writing a Python API and I have documented every class and function in the sources using *Google docstring* convention, which I find way more readable than the Sphinx convention. I want to use Sphinx to build the documentation for my API. There is an extension called *Napoleon* that supports *Numpydoc* and *Google docstrings*, so I tried to use it and I encountered several problems.
I am using Python 2.7.3 on Ubuntu 12.04.

I have Sphinx 1.1.3 installed. I did the first steps for the doc (`sphinx-quickstart`, with the `autodoc` enabled and a make file). I read that before Sphinx 1.3, I had to add `sphinxcontrib.napoleon` as an extension in the `conf.py` of my doc. I did that, and got the error that the extension `napoleon` could not be found. I downloaded it, installed it, and then I had the error that a certain package could not be found :

> Could not import extension sphinxcontrib.napoleon (exception: cannot import name six)

This was the name of a package in the requirement file, so I installed it. I had the same error with another package, I installed it also. Now I have the same error but with "range":

> Could not import extension sphinxcontrib.napoleon (exception: cannot import name range).

I don´t know which package it is, I haven´t found it anywhere, so I´m stuck. I tried ´sphinx.ext.napoleon´ just in case but it couldn't find the extension, which was expected.

I wanted to try then with Sphinx 1.3 and ´sphinx.ext.napoleon´ that should be shipped with Sphinx. When installing with apt-get, I only get version 1.1.3, even after an update. So I tried downloading directly and installing Sphinx 1.3, but got the following errors :

> ```
> Processing ./Sphinx-1.3.4.tar.gz
>     Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>     /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'entry_points'
>       warnings.warn(msg)
>     /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'extras_require'
>       warnings.warn(msg)
>     /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'include_package_data'
>       warnings.warn(msg)
>     /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'zip_safe'
>       warnings.warn(msg)
>     /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
>       warnings.warn(msg)
> ```

It seems to be a problem with setuptools. I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050576/migration-from-distribute-to-setuptools) and tried the solution but I cannot get it to work.

I know I could change all my docstring but that would take time and be less readable. I can try something else than Sphinx but Sphinx is the most common documentation tool for Python, that´s why I tried to stick with it.

How can I get a good documentation (still automatically) made from the *Google docstring* in my sources ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`range` is a `python` built-in, whose behavior changed in `python3`. There could be some fight between `python`, `sphinx` and `napoleon` versions/requirements (`sphinx 1.1.3` is rather old).

With concern to your last question (automatic documentation), you should look into the [`autodoc`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html) extension. If you want even more automation, look into the [apidoc](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/man/sphinx-apidoc.html) script, which is included in `sphinx > 1.1`.

It is not a direct solution/answer to your problem, but you could also use a more up-to-date and robust `python` distribution such as [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) (rather than the stale python in the Ubuntu repos), which would allow you to use the most recent `napoleon` and `sphinx` versions without much hassle.

Comment: I am already using the autodoc extension and the apidoc scripts, which work fine, but don´t convert Google docstrings to rps. I will look into Anaconda.

Comment: sure, that's because you need to get `napoleon` working, he's the one who does the job of interpreting the Google-style docstrings

Comment: Yes I know, and that´s the core of my problem. There should be a way to make napoleon work without installing a whole new python distribution, no ?

Comment: In your original question, *automation* appeared as a separate issue, that's the reason for my answer. Next time, don't add irrelevant details to your question.

Comment: No, automation is not a separate issue, because if I did not want it to be automatic, I would not have docstrings in a certain format already in the sources, and I could just write new documentation in another form. Plus I said I was already using autodoc. I also specified automation in case someone wanted to propose a completely different way than with Sphinx, it would have then to have automatic doc available. I clearly said my problem was, and still is, with Google docstring. Thank you for trying to help though.

Comment: ok ok, I get your point, sorry for being rude. Anyway, about the python distribution, switching to Anaconda is a matter of minutes, so I think it's worth a shot.

Comment: I tried Anaconda, and it seems to not have any problem with the napoleon extension, cheers. However there are some packages that I need installed for my code (rospkg, pocketsphinx) and anaconda doesn´t seem to want to install them (no result with ´conda search´, nor pip). I am left with building my doc with Anaconda (with import statements commented) and returning to system python for developing, it works, but that´s not an ideal solution.

Comment: even within Anaconda, you can `pip install` anything you want from `pypi`, since `conda` and `pip` can work together. What problem are you experiencing with `pip install rospkg` and `pip search pocketsphinx`?

Comment: Although pocketsphinx is on pypi, I get this weirdly unexplanatory error after `pip install pocketsphinx` :  `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pocketsphinx (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pockets
phinx` 
When I do `pip search pocketsphinx`, I get an `SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]`. I don´t really know how to get around those SSL certification errors, I´m at work and can´t mess around too much. (Same happens with `rospkg`)

Comment: try the following: `conda update openssl cryptography` and then `conda update certifi` ([source](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/494#issuecomment-155097614))

Comment: I had to install certify, then I updated in order but same results. And even with ssl_verify set to False, I still get the exact same errors... I will search and try to fix this and maybe open a new question for it since it´s getting pretty far from the original question. Thanks for the help.